# String response not getting in .getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

My controller method just return String value. When I called JSON from my view page, I don't see any value.

controller method

```
public string test(int i)
{
    return "Hello world " + i;
}
```

Inside View,

```
$.getJSON(['../Feeds/test/', 1, '/'].join(''),
function(json) {
    alert(json.toString());
});
```

If I run this into Mozilla, I can see "Hello world 1" in response but don't get any alert. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because it is not a json object? I am not sure because never try return plain text output with `getJSON`. why don't try `get` function?

```
$.get(['../Feeds/test/', 1, '/'].join(''), 
  function(json) {
   alert(json.toString());
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either make your controller return a `JsonResult`

```
return new JsonResult{Data = "Hello world " + i, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
```

or  use jquery's `$.get()` which doesn't expect a json object.